# Unity "File" button opening a separate window when automounting USB

Tags: unity, 14.04, usb, nautilus, automount

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and whenever I plug an USB drive it automounts it normally and opens a Nautilus window. However, when I change to another window and then try to return to my files by clicking the Nautilus button on the Unity panel it opens a new window  pointing to my home directory. Only when I Alt+Tab to the previously opened window can I access the USB files.

Is there some sort of configuration associated with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try scroll over icon (without click)

Comment: That works, but it kinda defeats the purpose of having a button.

Answer (score 1):

Unity added more functionality to hover scroll in many places. like: window switcher, desktop switcher, launcher icon...

Just Scroll over icon (without click)

Comment: Well, that is not the expected functionality

Answer (score -1):

This problem happens when using automount, even if you automat a parition on your disk. I am going to wait for the next release of nautilus and hope it goes away. An alternative is to use nemo file manager. webupd8.org has the files to update you system and you can set it as the default file manager. Problem then goes away.

Comment: Nemo is available in the official repositories. No need to add a PPA.

Comment: So, it's a Nautilus issue rather than a Unity issue. I wonder why they changed it, it was working fine on 12.04